# spring cloud contract docker not publishing to artifactory

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Following the steps described [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs/blob/sc-contract/spring-cloud-contract.adoc), I ran

```
 1. git clone https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs
 2. cd spring-cloud-contract-nodejs
 3. npm install
 4. npm test
```

Build is successful, however I don't see the artifacts getting published to artifcatory.
[image]

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-26:~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs$ git status On branch sc-contract Your branch is up to date with 'origin/sc-contract'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-26:~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs$ npm install

up to date in 24s

14 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-26:~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs$ npm test

> bookstore@1.0.0 test
> ./run_tests.sh



Running tests against Artifactory


~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs/docker ~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs Killing docker_artifactory_1 ... done Killing docker_mongo_1       ... done ~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs Fetching submodules Entering 'spring-cloud-contract-nodejs-external-contracts' fatal: couldn't find remote ref master fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for spring-cloud-contract-nodejs-external-contracts . Building docker ~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs/docker ~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs Going to remove docker_artifactory_1, docker_mongo_1 Removing docker_artifactory_1 ... done Removing docker_mongo_1       ... done mongo uses an image, skipping Building artifactory Sending build context to Docker daemon   7.68kB Step 1/4 : FROM docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.5.1  ---> add606aca80a Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER Marcin Grzejszczak <mgrzejszczak@pivotal.io>  ---> Using cache  ---> cbb8dd3f2cff Step 3/4 : COPY artifactory.config.import.yml /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.config.import.yml  ---> Using cache  ---> 46f1452932fd Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/entrypoint-artifactory.sh"]  ---> Using cache  ---> c8261b8fe68c Successfully built c8261b8fe68c Successfully tagged docker_artifactory:latest Creating docker_artifactory_1 ... done Creating docker_mongo_1       ... done ~/spring-cloud-contract-nodejs Waiting for 30 seconds for artifactory to boot properly Failed to kill app Working around certificate issues npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v17.2.0 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v17.2.0 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-12-16T20_30_09_497Z-debug.log Failed to install packages npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v17.2.0 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-12-16T20_30_09_937Z-debug.log Failed to install package nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out' Sc Contract Version [3.1.0] Application URL [http://172.18.0.1:9876] Artifactory URL [http://172.18.0.1:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local] Project Version [0.0.1.RELEASE] Setting project name to [bookstore] Running the build To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon. Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project : Will use contracts from the mounted [/contracts] folder

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootJarMainClassName
> Task :bootJar SKIPPED
> Task :jar
> Task :copyContracts
> Task :generateClientStubs
> Task :verifierStubsJar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
> Task :generateContractTests

> Task :compileContractTestJava Note: /spring-cloud-contract/build/generated-test-sources/contractTest/java/contracts/ContractVerifierTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
-Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :compileContractTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processContractTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :contractTestClasses

> Task :contractTest 2021-12-16 20:31:43.487  INFO 136 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.11.0 (camel-1) shutting down (timeout:45s) 2021-12-16 20:31:43.495  INFO 136 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes shutdown summary (total:0 stopped:0) 2021-12-16 20:31:43.498  INFO 136 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.11.0 (camel-1) shutdown in 11ms (uptime:1s480ms) Results: (2 tests, 2 successes, 0 failures, 0 skipped)

> Task :cleanOutput UP-TO-DATE

> Task :copyOutput Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':copyOutput' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':bootJarMainClassName' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':compileContractTestGroovy' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':compileContractTestJava' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':contractTest' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':copyContracts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':generateClientStubs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':generateContractTests' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':processContractTestResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/spring-cloud-contract/build'. Reason: Task ':copyOutput' uses this output of task ':verifierStubsJar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :check
> Task :build
> Task :publishToMavenLocal SKIPPED
> Task :publish UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness. Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 33s 16 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

Comment: I've updated the sample to use the latest spring cloud contract version. Can you try again please?

Comment: No it's still not working @MarcinGrzejszczak